# Correspondence between dual center and linear characters of finite reductive group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $(G,F)$ be a connected reductive group defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$ via the Frobenius $F$ and let $(G^*,F^*)$ be a group in duality with $(G,F)$ with respect to rational maximal tori $T \subseteq G$ and $T^* \subseteq G^*$.

My question is about a part of Proposition 13.30 and its proof in 'Representations of Finite Groups of Lie Type' by Digne-Michel.

> For $s \in Z(G^*)^F$ there exists a linear character $\widehat{s} \in \text{Irr}(G^F)$ such that $(T,\widehat{s}|_{T^F})$ corresponds to $(T^*,s)$ under duality.

This correspondence is given by an isomorphism
$$\text{Irr}(T^F) \cong X(T)/(F-1)X(T) \cong Y(T^*)/(F-1)Y(T^*) \cong  {T^*}^{F^*}$$
where the central isomorphism comes from duality, the left one comes from restriction $X(T) \to X(T^F) \cong \text{Irr}(T^F)$ and the right one is the composition of evaluation $Y(T) \to T$ at a certain root of unity and taking the so called norm map ${T^*}^{{F^*}^n} \to {T^*}^{F^*}$.

The proof of the statement goes roughly as follows. Let $(T,\theta)$ correspond to $(T^*,s)$ under duality.

1. Since $s$ is central, all roots of $G^*$ vanish on $s$. (no problem here)
2. By duality, $\theta$ vanishes on the rational points of the subtorus of $T$ generated by the coroots of $G$.
3. This subtorus is precisely $T' = T \cap [G,G]$. (no problem here)
4. The bijective map $T/T' \to G/[G,G]$ gives an isomorphism $\text{Irr}(G^F/[G,G]^F) \to \text{Irr}(T^F/T'^F)$. (no problem here)

Note that what is proved here is actually stronger than the claim since $[G,G]^F \neq [G^F,G^F]$. And I believe this is a problem.

Namely, if $(G,F)$ is semisimple, then $[G,G] = G$ and so every element of $Z(G^*)^{F^*}$ would have to correspond to the trivial character but since we have a bijection $\text{Irr}(T^F) \cong {T^*}^{F^*}$, this would mean that $Z(G^*)^{F^*}$ would have to be trivial.

But for this $G = PGL_n$ and $G^* = SL_n$ are already counterexamples (for $n = q - 1$ for example).

The statements in 1., 3. and 4. seem Ok for me, so the problem (if I am not missing something) seems to lie with part 2.
I believe the problem here is that if $\gamma \in Y(T^*)$ maps to $s$ under $Y(T^*)/(F-1)Y(T^*) \cong {T^*}^{F^*}$ then even though $s$ vanishes under the roots of $G^*$, the cocharacter $\gamma$ does not have to do the same.

I believe this is only a problem if $Z(G^*)$ is not connected, since for every $s \in {Z(G^*)^\circ}^{F^*}$ we find a preimage in $Y(T^*)$ which vanishes under the roots of $G^*$.

It would be great if someone could check if my thoughts are correct, and if they are not (which I hope), then I would be grateful for any clarification.

Comment: You're right that there is a problem here. You should look at Bonnafé's "Sur les caractères des groupes réductifs finis à centre non connexe" which is Astérisque 306. Specifically look at §9.D where this issue is dealt with. More generally, you've clearly got to a decent level with Deligne--Lusztig theory. I would highly recommend reading the early parts of Cédric's monograph, especially Chapter 3. It really clarifies some of the mess of Digne--Michel's text.

Comment: @JayTaylor Thank you for your comment. I am familiar with Bonnafé's text or at least the parts of it you named. Also, Prop. 2.5 and Cor. 2.6 (which is not really a corollary since the isomorphism $T'/T \cong G'/G$ as algebraic groups is not that trivial) can be used to prove the above statement for elements in the connected center. I figured out that by taking a regular embedding for $G^*$, one can reduce the statement above to this case. I shall write a complete answer to my question when I have more time on my hands.